# cell showing up as "-c-" in table?

Tags: tables, tex-core

Where did I go wrong to have the -c- show up in the cell? I just want the text "`bar`" there. sorry I am new

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|*{4}{wc{0.5\mycolwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & {|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{All Sites} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{NRH Sites} \\
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{foo} & {|c|}{} & Pre-QC & Post-QC  & Pre-QC & Post-QC   \\
\hline
 A & 127 & 99.80  & 99.94 & 99.68 & 99.89 \\
 B & 318 & 99.90 & 99.95 & 99.88 & 99.93 \\
 C& 277 & 99.91 & 99.96 & 99.90 & 99.96 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A `|` in text mode renders as `-`. Try using math mode (`$|c|$`).

Comment: How did you define `\mycolwidth`?

Answer (score 2):

What are the `{|c|}{}` bits doing? You possibly wanted `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}`, but you can just omit it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newlength{\mycolwidth}
\setlength{\mycolwidth}{3cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|*{4}{wc{\dimexpr0.5\mycolwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
\hline
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{All Sites} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{NRH Sites} \\
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{foo} & & Pre-QC & Post-QC  & Pre-QC & Post-QC   \\
\hline
 A & 127 & 99.80  & 99.94 & 99.68 & 99.89 \\
 B & 318 & 99.90 & 99.95 & 99.88 & 99.93 \\
 C& 277 & 99.91 & 99.96 & 99.90 & 99.96 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe looking to create something like this?

[image]

Observe that the `{|c|}{}` bits are gone.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newlength\mycolwidth
\setlength\mycolwidth{4cm} % or some other suitable value

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|*{4}{wc{0.5\mycolwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}}
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{All Sites} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{NRH Sites} \\
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{foo} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
 Pre-QC & Post-QC & Pre-QC & Post-QC   \\
\hline
 A & 127 & 99.80 & 99.94 & 99.68 & 99.89 \\
 B & 318 & 99.90 & 99.95 & 99.88 & 99.93 \\
 C & 277 & 99.91 & 99.96 & 99.90 & 99.96 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```